# If/Else with Associations in Simple_Form - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, simple-form, form-for

I'm creating a job board where the individual job postings have associated regions > states > cities. A posting can have any number and combination of regions, states, or cities.

My Regions Schema looks like this:

```
  create_table "regions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "parent"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "role"
  end
```

and my `new` action withing my `Postings` controller looks like this:

```
  def new
    @posting = current_user.recruiter_postings.build
    @major_regions = Region.where(:role => "region")
    @state_regions = Region.where(:role => "state")
    @city_regions = Region.where(:role => "city")
  end
```

I'm attempting to create an accordian style checkbox selector using Regions, States (where `state.parent === region.id`) and Cities (where `city.parent === state.id`).

Example:

[image]

Regions use a join table association to my Postings ActiveRecord.

Here is my `Posting` model:

```
class Posting < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  belongs_to :recruiter, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :interests
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  has_and_belongs_to_many :job_types
  has_and_belongs_to_many :industries
  has_and_belongs_to_many :regions
  has_and_belongs_to_many :market_caps
  has_and_belongs_to_many :ownerships
  has_many :users, through: :interests
  acts_as_followable
end
```

And here is my `Region` model:

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :postings
  has_and_belongs_to_many :news_items
  has_and_belongs_to_many :mkt_ints
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

In my `postings/_form.html.haml` file I need to show all of the appropriate checkboxes Regions > States > Cities and allow them all to be saved through an association:

```
  %ul.major-region-ul
  - @major_regions.each do |region|
    %li
      = f.label :regions, region.name
      = f.check_box :regions
      - @state_regions.each do |state|
        -if state.parent === region.id
          %ul.state-region-ul
            %li
              = f.label :regions, state.name
              = f.check_box :regions
              - @city_regions.each do |city|
                -if city.parent === state.id
                  %ul.city-region-ul
                    %li
                      = f.label :regions, city.name
                      = f.check_box :regions
```

When I set them as check_boxes (as seen above) they display correctly, but will not save. When I attempt to display and save them as associations:

```
  %ul.major-region-ul
  - @major_regions.each do |region|
    %li
      = f.label :regions, region.name
      = f.association :regions
      - @state_regions.each do |state|
        -if state.parent === region.id
          %ul.state-region-ul
            %li
              = f.label :regions, state.name
              = f.association :regions
              - @city_regions.each do |city|
                -if city.parent === state.id
                  %ul.city-region-ul
                    %li
                      = f.label :regions, city.name
                      = f.association :regions
```

**edit**

[smathy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152786/smathy) helped solve this issue

---

I get `undefined method "associations" for #<SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x0000010ccc82a8>`

---

But it now generates every `Region` for each success within the `if else` statements, which is still a big issue I don't know how to deal with and I'd appreciate assistance.

Here is my application trace:

```
app/views/postings/_form.html.haml:13:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_postings__form_html_haml__3504097481979586058_2278688540'
app/views/postings/_form.html.haml:10:in `block in _app_views_postings__form_html_haml__3504097481979586058_2278688540'
app/views/postings/_form.html.haml:3:in `_app_views_postings__form_html_haml__3504097481979586058_2278688540'
app/views/postings/edit.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_postings_edit_html_erb__478558825236209135_2272129060'
```

I can not figure out how to both 1. maintain the association and 2. display the options correctly. I can do one or the other, but not both.

I appreciate any assistance you can provide.

Let me know if you need any further information.

Thanks!